# Lower accuracy of VGG16 using data augmentation in Keras

Tags: neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction

I have a question regarding feature extraction with data augmentation in Keras.  I am building a dog breed classifier.

By feature extraction, I am referring to extending the model, (conv_base, VGG16) by adding Dense layers on top, and running the whole thing end to end on the input data. This will allow me to use data augmentation, because every input image goes through the convolutional base every time it’s seen by the model.

Training Set:  6680 images belonging to 133 classes

Validation Set: 835 images belonging to 133 classes

Test Set: 836 images belonging to 133 classes

I was able to successfully implement data augmentation and feature extraction independently of one another but when I try combining the 2, my accuracy is coming out incredibly small for some reason.  Why is this?  Am I doing something majorly wrong with my approach?

```python
from keras.applications import VGG16

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                  include_top=False,
                  input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

model = Sequential()

model.add(conv_base)

conv_base.trainable = False

model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())

model.add(Dense(133, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen_aug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,)

test_datagen_aug = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator_aug = train_datagen_aug.flow_from_directory(
    'myImages/train',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=50,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator_aug = test_datagen_aug.flow_from_directory(
        'myImages/valid',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')

checkpointer_aug = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='saved_models/dogs_transfer_aug_model.h5', 
                            save_best_only=True)

history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator_aug,
      steps_per_epoch=130,
      epochs=20,
      validation_data=validation_generator_aug,
      verbose=1,
      callbacks=[checkpointer_aug],
      validation_steps=26)
```

Output looks like this:

```python
Epoch 1/20
130/130 [==============================] - 293s - loss: 15.9044 - acc: 0.0083 - val_loss: 16.0019 - val_acc: 0.0072
Epoch 2/20
130/130 [==============================] - 281s - loss: 15.9972 - acc: 0.0075 - val_loss: 15.9977 - val_acc: 0.0075
Epoch 3/20
130/130 [==============================] - 280s - loss: 16.0220 - acc: 0.0060 - val_loss: 15.9977 - val_acc: 0.0075
Epoch 4/20
130/130 [==============================] - 280s - loss: 15.9941 - acc: 0.0077 - val_loss: 16.0019 - val_acc: 0.0072
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what "feature extraction" refers to? Also, can you confirm, do you have the same issue if you use `train_datagen_aug = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)` to match `test_datagen_aug`

Comment: Bear with me because I am relatively new to DL but I am extending the model, (conv_base) by adding Dense layers on top, and running the whole thing end to end on the input data. This will allow you to use data augmentation, because every input image goes through the convolutional base every time it’s seen by the model.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. By "feature extraction" do you mean the use of the VGG network as a base? Or to the extra layers you added on top? Or something else?

Comment: Yes I am using VGG as the base.

Comment: Ok that's clear. The first thing I would test is whether the same problem occurs if you remove the augmentation, i.e. set `train_datagen_aug = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)` as per my previous comment. Since you are using a pretrained model it is important that your preprocessing steps match what were used to train that model. It could be that your data are incorrectly scaled, or your colour channels may be in the wrong order. Once you have got it working without augmentation, only then would I add the augmentation back in.

Comment: Ok.  I will give that a try!

Comment: Try using a lower learning rate for `rmsprop`. You can do so by changing the optimizer to this:  `optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=X)`. Put `1e-5` or `2e-5` in place of `X` and see what happens. Don't forger to add this line: `from keras import optimizers`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend it is model over fitting issue as shown in model's loss and accuracy. We can have a go with a smaller version (with reduced layers) of VGG16

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D

NUMBER_OF_TRAINING_SAMPLES = 6668 
NUMBER_OF_VALIDATION_SAMPLES = 835 # let's say you have 400 dogs and 400 cats
batch_size = 32
out_classes = 133
input_shape=(224, 224, 3)

def buildSmallVGG(out_classes, input_shape):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1),input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Conv2D(16, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))


    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Dense(out_classes, activation='softmax'))
    return model

model = buildSmallVGG(out_classes, input_shape)

history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator_aug,
      steps_per_epoch=NUMBER_OF_TRAINING_SAMPLES // batch_size,
      epochs=20,
      validation_data=validation_generator_aug,
      callbacks=[checkpointer_aug],
      validation_steps=NUMBER_OF_VALIDATION_SAMPLES // batch_size)
```

The above is not tested. Would be good if you could share your results on what you get in loss, accuracy etc.